# Expand table 2 based on entry table 1 - results in formula inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using VBA to expand table thus it resulted in some inconsistent formula in column in table 2 by skipping the range in table for example `ROW($S$10:S11)` the next cell in the same column skips a cell `"S12" & ROW($S$10:S13)` which can be fix using error audit and restore to calculated column but I would like to have it to automatically fix that error using VBA any help?

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject
    Dim bError As Byte   

    Set tbl1 = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
    Set tbl2 = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("table2")

    If tbl1.Range.Rows.Count <> tbl2.Range.Rows.Count Then
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("table2[#All]").Resize(tbl1.Range.Rows.Count)    
        tbl2.Resize rng
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be using table references when using a table.

Comment: Have a look into this guide: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) it explains very well how to handle table objects in VBA correctly.